# How can I undo the `HasDefaultValueSql` in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-fluent-api

How can I undo the `HasDefaultValueSql` in EF Core?

I have a class which implements the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` interface. In that class I have the:

```
builder.Property(myProp => myProp.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newid()");
```

Now, the `newid()` is SQL Server specific. While in tests I am using the SQLite and would like to generate the `Id` value in a different manner. I found out that with SQLite I can use the:

```
builder.Property(myProp => myProp.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

The above code I added into a new class, which implements the `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. I created the `DbContext` for tests, which inherits from the app `DbContext`. Now in the `DbContext` for tests in the `OnModelCreating` I first apply the base class configurations and after that the configuration which uses the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` call.

Now the problem is that the `HasDefaultValueSql` is not gone and I am getting the error `SQLite Error 1: 'unknown function: newid()'.`. So, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
builder.Property(myProp => myProp.Id).UndoDefaultValueSetup().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Is it possible somehow? Also, in order to avoid the x-y problem here I am open to suggestions on how I could generate the GUID in SQLite + EF Core configuration otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional code, and check for context.Database.IsSqlServer.

Comment: Works well. Thank you.